# Automatic restart of multi-instance Datastage job with DSJE_BADSTATE fail status

Tags: python, db2, datastage

We have a Datastage job that runs on multiple instances on different job cycles. The job could run concurrently or on different times. When one job cycle fails due to the failed Datastage job in that cycle, the other cycles fail as well. Is there a way to prevent this from happening i.e., if the Datastage failed in one cycle, can the other cycle continue to run using the same Datastage job that failed in the other cycle. Is there a way we can do an automatic reset of the failed job? If so, how? Thanks for you info and help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's requested of questions to provide a [minimum reproducible example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so as to allow others to effectively diagnose your issue. Could you update your question with attempted solutions and an MRE?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up automatic reset only by wrapping each cycle variant in its own sequence. Only sequence jobs support automatic reset after failure, as a property of the Job activity.
I'm not sure what the case is if another cycle is running when you try to reset. You could test this.  It may be that, if you need this reset functionality, you need clones rather than instances of the job.

Comment: Thank you @Ray Wurlod. Yes, we're looking into putting that into its own sequence. We're exploring if there any other options out there. Regards. :).